# How to get data of a previous year for a specifed date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have the query below, to display the Sales by Rayon & Store, for a specific date :

```
SELECT
    [DATE] = GL_DATEPIECE
    [STORE] = GL_ETABLISSEMENT,
    [RAYON] = GL_FAMILLENIV1,
    [SALES] = SUM([GL_TOTALTTC])
FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM
WHERE GL_DATEPIECE BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-11-02'
GROUP BY GL_ETABLISSEMENT, GL_FAMILLENIV1, GL_DATEPIECE
```

I want to add another column : `[Sales Y-]` to bring Sales for previous year of the date specifed in the clause where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    [DATE] = GL_DATEPIECE
    [STORE] = GL_ETABLISSEMENT,
    [RAYON] = GL_FAMILLENIV1,
    [SALES] = SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GL_DATEPIECE) = 2019 THEN [GL_TOTALTTC] ELSE 0 END)
    [SALES Y-] = SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(GL_DATEPIECE) = 2018 THEN [GL_TOTALTTC] ELSE 0 END)
FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM
WHERE 
    GL_DATEPIECE BETWEEN '2019-11-01' AND '2019-11-02'
    OR GL_DATEPIECE BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-02'
GROUP BY GL_ETABLISSEMENT, GL_FAMILLENIV1, GL_DATEPIECE
```

Comment: Thank you GMB. The point is i want to use a stored parametre (With Start & end date). How could i change the years 2019 and 2018 please ?